# server cuts fields from csv to first 50 chars of string when importing to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import data from csv to mysql table via phpmyadmin and I have the problem. Fields which length is more than 50 characters are cut off.
I can't see any option to repair this
Can anybody help me?

result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`:

Table
Create Table
sklep
CREATE TABLE `sklep` (
 `product_id` varchar(256)...

Comment: Please add table definition and a few lines from csv

Comment: Look at the column datatypes. Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` and post the result in your question.

Comment: the datatypes of columns are almost always text

Comment: You have not published the whole table definition

Comment: it's cut off by phpmyadmin

Comment: Perhaps that's the problem with your import too..Run the show create from command line